# Azure Loadbalancer PORT issuse

Tags: azure

I have azure Vm with loadbalancer . I have opened port in VM and also have updated port open rule in loadbalancer .

Still port is seems like not opened . Please help in this  .

Comment: one VM? use NAT or load balancer rules?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the health-probe configuration and the load balancing rules configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Does VM created with NSG? If yes, we should **add inbound rules to NSG** for that port.
Also we should check the **probe**, only when the probe find the VM is health, the LB will route network traffic to this VM.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.